# What javascript code do i have to add to make this div scroll horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made this page with *three sections* that have **full width and height**, but i don't know how to make them scroll *horizontally* and ***not vertically***, i tried this source:
[CSS-tricks: Horizontal scrolling](https://www.css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/#article-header-id-1) but it doesn't work on my code...

Here is my code:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.element {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
.element1 { background: pink; }
.element2 { background: lightgreen; }
.element3 { background: lightblue; }
```

```html
<div class="element element1">Element #1</div>
<div class="element element2">Element #2</div>
<div class="element element3">Element #3</div>
```

Comment: Your code is fine, you just forgot to include jQuery and jQuery mousewheel plugin, see my answer below for a working demo :) goodluck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal scrolling is working as expected,  please check the code below. From your reference the demo uses a jquery plugin. You need to include jQuery and jQuery mousewheel plugin for it to work. :)

```js
$(function() {

   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    
      event.preventDefault();

   });

});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.element {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
.element1 { background: pink; }
.element2 { background: lightgreen; }
.element3 { background: lightblue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<div class="element element1">Element #1</div>
<div class="element element2">Element #2</div>
<div class="element element3">Element #3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change body style

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing some js files in your page. Make sure to add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
    $(".post").wrap("<td></td>");
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is a JSFiddle with a working example
https://jsfiddle.net/ybvsyt0p/

Answer (score 0):

I think using JavaScript together with your CSS will produce the "Horizontal Scroll" effect you need:
Define HTML AND BODY as selectors use a base method like "mousewheel", and notice the placement and scope of `this` as it references its parent object (the page) via mousewheel.
 `delta` can be used to work with values that are consistent with the user interaction and scrollLeft is a property in CSS 2 and a method in CSS 3 (I.e., `scrollLeft()` works in most browsers.

```
$("html, body").mousewheel(
        function
                (event, delta) {
                      this.scrollLeft *= -30;
                 }
  )
```